# Directly proving one set is a superset of another

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

> Prove the following theorem directly:
>
> **Theorem**
> Let $E,M$ be sets. If $E \supseteq M$, then $E \supseteq M \cup E$.

**Proof:**
Assume $E,M$ are sets where $E$ is a superset of $M$.

Since $E$ is a superset of $M$, does that mean if every $x$ contains $M$ then it is also in $E$?
And to verify or show that $E$ is a superset of $M \cup E$, would we have to use a different element like $x^2$ to further prove the validity?
I'm new to using proofs using set theory and I would like to understand the proper way of working with these types of problems.

Comment: This isn't really ``set theory" so to speak and your question is not very clear as stated. Are you trying to prove that $M\subset E$? In that case all you have to show is that $x\in E$ if $x\in M$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINTS**

1. If $E$ is a superset of $M$, then $M$ is contained in $E$, so if $x \in M$, then $x \in E$ as well.
2. If you want to show $A \supseteq B \cup C$, then assume $x \in B \cup C$ (hence either $x \in B$ or $x \in C$) and then show that $x \in A$.